# sampling order sum from different order size and probabilities

Tags: sampling, binomial-distribution

I want to analyze the probable outcomes of an order pipeline for a business. Say we have ten potential orders, each (business) order has a different size (OS), say 1, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9 (mio) and the probability of getting each order (PO) is different say 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 0.9, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 0.9.

What is normally done is to calculate sum(OS*PO) (OS1*PO1+OS2*PO2....OSn*POn), but as the size of the orders vary greatly, this way may return an outcome that in no way reflects the probable variations, especially if one large order dominates the pipeline. This may result in people have to be laid off for no reason, or not enough employed to produce a given order. As I'm entirely new to R (and eager to learn) I hope than you may be able to help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured it out, and since no-one answered my quite vague question, this is what I came up with for R.

```
set.seed(1)
library(pastecs)
rm(list = ls())
#genererer (TRUE/FALSE med proba sandsynlighed for TRUE, n = size)
TRUEGEN <- function(proba, size) sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size, prob = c(proba, 1 - proba),
                                    replace = TRUE)
#Genererer 100.000 binomialfordelte TRUE/FALSE-værdier og gemmer i Truepool "values"
Truepool <-TRUEGEN(0.50, 100000)
NTPIPE <- as.data.frame(1:100000)

ordercalc <- function(proba, size){ 
Truepool <- TRUEGEN(proba, 100000)
Ordersize <- rep.int(size, 100000)
Truepool*Ordersize
}
NTPIPE$order1 <- ordercalc(0.99, 101300000)
NTPIPE$order2 <- ordercalc(1, 20000010)
NTPIPE$order3 <- ordercalc(0.8, 64000200)
NTPIPE$order4 <- ordercalc(0.8, 28001000)
NTPIPE$order5 <- ordercalc(0.75, 91000000)
NTPIPE$order6 <- ordercalc(0.75, 61000000)
NTPIPE$order7 <- ordercalc(0.75, 210700000)
NTPIPE$order8 <- ordercalc(0.95, 2840000)
NTPIPE$order9 <- ordercalc(0.95, 4900000)
NTPIPE$order10 <- ordercalc(0.75, 440780000)
NTPIPE$order11 <- ordercalc(0.9, 422126000)
NTPIPE$order12 <- ordercalc(0.9, 1224800000)

NTPIPE$outcomeValue <- NTPIPE$order1+
 NTPIPE$order2+
NTPIPE$order3+
NTPIPE$order4+
NTPIPE$order5+
NTPIPE$order6+
NTPIPE$order7+
NTPIPE$order8+
NTPIPE$order9+
NTPIPE$order10+
NTPIPE$order11+
NTPIPE$order12

 mean((NTPIPE$outcomeValue))
#grafer
par(mfrow=c(1,3),oma=c(0,0,2,0))
sum(NTPIPE$outcomeValue < 35, na.rm=TRUE)/length(NTPIPE$outcomeValue)
NTPIPE$outcomeValue <- NTPIPE$outcomeValue/1000000
vertic.line <- mean(NTPIPE$outcomeValue)
hist(NTPIPE$outcomeValue, 
 main = '100k simuleringer af 3 mdr pipeline', 
 xlab = 'total ordresum, mio DKK', 
 ylab = 'antal resultater i hver kategori for ordresum', 
 border = 'blue', 
 breaks = 20, 
 )
  abline(v=vertic.line, col = "red")

 boxplot(NTPIPE$outcomeValue)
  abline(h=vertic.line, col = "red")
 title("3 mdr ordrepipeline", outer=TRUE)

 limits <- min(NTPIPE$outcomeValue):max(NTPIPE$outcomeValue)  
 limits
 lengthNT <- length(limits)
 akkusum <- NULL

 for (j in 1:lengthNT){                                                     
 temp <- sum(NTPIPE$outcomeValue > limits[j] ,          na.rm=TRUE)/length(NTPIPE$outcomeValue)
 akkusum <- append(akkusum, temp)  
 }
 akkusum
 plot(limits, akkusum, xlab = "turnover in mio", ylab =     "prob of turnover exceeding x", ylim = c(0,1) )
 abline(v=vertic.line, col = "red")
```